# BigQuery, querying the streaming buffer & a partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to query data from BigQuery which is in the most recent partition, but also in the streaming buffer.

Ideally I would like to stream data into a more granular partition than a day, maybe using a decorator:

`mydataset.table$2017030112`

Following this, I would query the table for the partition & the buffer.

```
SELECT * FROM `mydataset.table` 
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL 
AND _PARTITIONTIME IS 2017030112
```

The result should return just the partition data, regardless if it is in the buffer or not.

The issues / questions:

- Is it possible to partition more granular than by DAY?
- Would a query accessing the buffer and a partition charge just for the partition?
- Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Support here!

- It's not possible to partition more granular than a day.
- You are charged for the bytes that your query scans, When you query the streaming buffer, moreover, you are querying what's called an [unpartitioned partition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#creating_a_view_using_an_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables_pseudo_columns).
- Not that I can think of. This is the way to go.

I hope that helps